# Who made the 2013 Winter Bash snowflake script?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

This years 2013 Winter Bash canvas based [snowflake script](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) is quite lovely.

> [image: 2013-winter-bash-header]

If you don't mind my asking, to whom should credits be given for that?

There must be a unicorn in there somewhere...

Comment: Where abouts is live animated version of this

Comment: @RichardTingle It's on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. But note that it measures canvas drawing performance and falls back to a static image if it's not satisfactory, so if you just see a picture of non-moving snowflakes, your browser or computer may just not be fast enough.

Comment: @balpha it is beau_ti_ful

Comment: See also [How to generate a random snowflake](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39361/how-to-generate-a-random-snowflake). (@balpha)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I wrote it for last year's Winter Bash, and I actually [promised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983764/creating-falling-snow-using-html-5-and-js#comment19310621_13983764) to open source it after some code clean-up, which to my shame I still, one year later, haven't done yet.

I made it my mission that if Stack Exchange recycles the oldest JavaScript animation that exists on the internet, it should at least be a very nice-looking version. The snowflake movement is actually based on [an academic paper](http://www.create.aau.dk/Snow/snow.pdf) (and on a second one that's based on this one, but which I'm unable to find right now).

This year when working on Winter Bash, I was specifically ordered "not to spend a ridiculous amount of time on snow animation."

Comment: This is amazing to hear that you have researched a paper to bring the snow flakes animation.  Very nice, different shapes and sizes.  Merry Christmas in advance to you :)

Comment: With the larger flakes, judicious mouse-movement can keep them floating indefinitely (OK, I don't know about literally). Might it be possible theoretically to keep a snowflake stationary? I thought I got close, then there was a collision.

Comment: The time spent is only "ridiculous" if there is little or no ROI - a unicorn is well worth the time investment.

Comment: "I was specifically ordered..." - Sounds like some manager doesn't understand the true meaning of Winterbash, for shame!

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, he even [hides his pointy-haired head under a hat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146719/david-fullerton).

Comment: Still waiting for you to release it...

Comment: Still waiting for you to release it...

Comment: Any chance of this happening in the near future?

Comment: Hi @balpha, any news about your [promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983764/creating-falling-snow-using-html-5-and-js#comment19310621_13983764)?