# Is the "snow" effect on the Winter Bash page open source?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

I don't know if it's the right place to ask this, please correct me if that's the case.

The "snow" effect on the Winter Bash page is pretty cool, is that an open source plugin? I was looking at the code, but it's (obviously) minified/obfuscated. Is it something we can use ourselves?

Comment: [Shame on me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213043/who-made-the-2013-winter-bash-snowflake-script/213045#comment803696_213045) :(

Comment: @balpha Yes indeed. Go fix it! If you do it in January, technically you won't spend that time 'this year'... Keeps the bosses happy :)

Comment: @balpha Nice work, can you not even show us it in it's *untidied* state? I won't judge :)