# Add frozen/winter metaphor to a frozen chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat, frozen-rooms

When a chat room is frozen, would be possible to add a metaphor of a frozen, winter like screen. I believe that it would enhance the understanding of the situation and it is a "nice to have" feature.

The current timeout feature already have one neat animation of a countdown, presenting us with a clear metaphor of a timer.

Maybe could use a snowfall animation, like one used on the "Winter Bash 2014"?
 Another possibly is tinting the screen with blue hue and adding a glass/ice texture.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213043/194162

Comment: There is a difference between snowfall and ice-bound; snowfall is more dynamic and livening, while ice-bound would be like behind a transparent glass wall with a blue tinge. If snowfall is used to indicate a frozen chat room, the same snowfall will not be reused for other meaning or purposes during the same Winter Bash period. Otherwise it will lose its purpose of indicating a frozen chatroom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Disney Frozen themed chatroom :D]

Yes, this certainly seems to enhance the situation. :D

Except that might be a bit too much of a [happy snowman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFatVn1hP3o) for such a sad situation...

Comment: ... but do you want to build a snowman?

Comment: Do you mean *[code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49671/do-you-want-to-code-a-snowman)* a snowman? ;)